# Solr installation on lucene based alfresco community edition

Tags: solr, lucene, alfresco

I am involved in a project which uses **alfresco 4.0.e** as its repository for content management. The alfresco has been customized and its default search indexing engine is **lucene**. Now, I want to upgrade to **alfresco 5.0.d** which uses Solr indexing engine instead of **Lucene**. How can I install **Solr** to this alfresco edition which does not have any previous **Solr** installations? Also to be noted that I am not using a setup wizard. I am using archived alfresco community edition from Alfresco site.

Comment: Why not just skip 5 and go straight to 6? The new docker container deployment should make your life a lot easier if you're not a sysadmin

Answer (score 1):

If you install Alfresco manually using the distribution zip, you will need to configure Solr 4 separately on the existing Alfresco installation using Tomcat.

You can find a detailed tutorial on the community : [Installing and configuring Solr 4](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/solr4-install-config.html)

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will work on it and notify you as soon as possible if I am successful in doing so.